# Adjoints and $\operatorname{im}{(u^\ast)}$: is the orthogonal complement of a closed subspace closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

Context (you may skip this part of my question):

Let $H,H'$ be Hilbert spaces and $u\in B(H)$ and let $u^\ast$ be the adjoint of $u$.

It is clear that $\operatorname{ker}{u^\ast} = (\operatorname{im}{u})^\bot$ because for all $h \in H, h' \in H'$:

$$ \langle u(h), h' \rangle = \langle h, u^\ast (h') \rangle$$

If $h' \in \operatorname{ker}{u^\ast}$ then this inner product vanishes and therefore  $\operatorname{ker}{u^\ast} \subseteq (\operatorname{im}{u})^\bot$. Similarly for $h' \in (\operatorname{im}{u})^\bot$.

Now my problem: my book states that "hence $\overline{(\operatorname{im}{u^\ast})} =(\operatorname{ker}{u})^\bot$".  I don't see how this is implied.

The kernels of $u$ and $u^\ast$ are both closed but doing the same argument as before, we get
 $$ \operatorname{im}{u^\ast} = (\operatorname{ker}{u})^\bot$$

but at this point there is no reason to believe that $(\operatorname{ker}{u})^\bot$ is closed.

> Hence my question:
>
> Is the orthogonal complement of a closed subspace closed?

Comment: For any subspace $S$ (might not closed) of $H$, $S^\perp$ is closed (try to show that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $x \in H$, the linear function $\phi_{x}(y)=(y,x)$ is continuous because $|\phi_{x}(y)-\phi_{x}(y')| \le \|y-y'\|\|x\|$. So the null space $\mathcal{N}(\phi_{x})=\phi_{x}^{-1}\{0\}$ is closed because it is the inverse image of the closed set $\{0\}$ under the continuous function $\phi_{x}$. And the following is closed because it is the intersection of closed sets:
$$
                 S^{\perp} = \bigcap_{s \in S}\mathcal{N}(\phi_{s})=\{ x : (x,s)=0 \mbox{ for all } s \in S\}.
$$
This proves $S^{\perp}$ is closed, regardless of the set $S\subseteq H$, closed or not.

Comment: It's weird in the book that they write closure of the image. It would be much clearer if they wrote that the image of $u^\ast$ is therefore, surprisingly, closed!